# how to force blocks of code to execute in redshift sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Our company runs our biz database on Amazon redshift sql.

Each of us have large blocks of sql code to run.  In order to avoid over-straining the system, we would like to have a way to force blocks of our code to execute before the next part of our code commences.

It looks like simply putting "go" in the passages of SQL code may achieve this, like so.

some SQL statements;
some SQL statements;

go

some more SQL statements;
some more SQL statements;

go

..ad nauseum.

Is that right, or should we try something else?  We're all ordinary end users; none of us have admin privileges.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question: your SQL blocks execution have to be managed by Orchestration/ETL/Job scheduler tool like Amazon Data Pipeline for example or use some custom made locking mechanism. Anyway your admin can create Redshift queue for you that will allow limited number of parallel executions and limit resources for your user only.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Yuri.  I gave up on getting a response from anyone, or would have responded sooner.  Since  your response matches what our BIT team is telling me I will assume it is correct.  Ultimately, the need that my question addresses is for non-DBA types to submit their code chunk-by-chunk to avoid swamping our system.  So that's why I was looking for a client-side way of achieving this.